# Outbound message NOT triggered with Custom Fields

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

Our outbound message is configured to trigger on any updates to our Case objects. However, testing shows that singular updates to our custom fields are not being observed. Updates ONLY to the standard Case fields are triggering the workflow.

Are there settings in the Case's template were you specify that custom-field updates should be observed?

Comment: Sounds like the workflow rule's evaluation criteria is "created, and every time it's edited" and what's the rule criteria? "formula evaluates to true" with a value of `true` in the box?

Comment: Please post your workflow rule... maybe a screenshot with all the settings visible.